# Domain Name protection

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I have purchased a domain name and I don't have plan to launch my website in the next few months. But one thing I am worrying about is that if in the mean time someone else uses my domain name for his/her website? Is it possible to do so? And if yes, how to protect my domain name?

Comment: A caveat to all the answers is if you have a shady registrar/webhost like GoDaddy, [who uses their customers' and ex-customers' domains as their own private billboards](http://www.thedomains.com/2010/05/03/class-action-filed-against-godaddy/). Of course, that shouldn't be too much of a surprise given Godaddy's historic ties with domain squatters and spammers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one would be able to use the domain unless they had access to the domain control panel and could set the nameservers to point towards their hosting. So unless someone gets hold of your domain control panel details, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 6):

If you've bought the domain name, then nobody else can buy it. It's yours, whether you put something on it or not. Don't worry :)

Comment: yes that is correct that no one can buy it but what happens when we create a account on an web hosting service, it asks us the domain name to use and if someone uses my domain name at that time?

Comment: There wouldn't be any point in them doing that, because if they don't own the domain, they can't point it to their own hosts. Only you can control which web host the domain points to.

Answer (score 1):

A domain name is nothing but a synonym for an IP address. What IP address is something you decide. Nobody can use your domain name, unless it points to the IP address of their server.

Answer (score 1):

As long as no one have access to your Domain Control Panel in your domain registrar, the domain name should be safe. To be on the safe side, most registrars allow you to lock a domain, which prevents any WHOIS changes for a couple of months.

Once the access is prevented, no one shall be able to use your domain name. Even if someone uses your domain name with a web host, they need access to the Domain Control Panel to change the nameservers of the domain name. Since the access is prevented and all changes locked, you are perfectly on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible. No one can use the domain name your purchased unless you give the permission to do so. Even though, if you had purchased it for now. Do not forgot to renew it on time. If you fail to do so, the domain name registration would get expired and your domain name would come to common pool. So, anyone could register. For restoration after expiry it would be too costly.